# Converting output of libc::getcwd into a string

Tags: rust, libc

I'd like to print out the result of `libc::getcwd`. My issue is that to create  `getcwd` takes an `i8` (`c_char`) buffer, whereas `String::from_utf8` needs a `u8` buffer. I started with:

```
static BUF_BYTES: usize = 4096;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut buf: Vec<i8> = Vec::with_capacity(BUF_BYTES as usize);
        libc::getcwd(buf.as_mut_ptr(), buf.len());
        let s = String::from_utf8(buf).expect("Found invalid UTF-8");
        println!("result: {}", s);
    }
}
```

Which produces the error:

```
14:32 error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::vec::Vec<u8>`,
    found `std::vec::Vec<i8>` [E0308]
```

Thanks to the comments, I changed the `buf` into a `Vec<u8>` and cast it to a `c_char` buffer in the `getcwd` call:

```
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(BUF_BYTES as usize);
    libc::getcwd(buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_char, buf.len());
```

This compiles but now, when printing the string it is empty (length: 0)

I found that `getcwd` returns NULL (`libc::getcwd(...).is_null()` is true), reading the last error via external crate `errno` (why is this a separate crate to libc?) reveals that `getcwd` fails with "Invalid argument". The source of the problem seems that `buf.len()` returns 0.

Comment: You could make `buf` a `Vec<u8>` and then call `libc::getcwd(buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut i8, buf.len())`. Or something like that.

Comment: One note: there is no guarantee that the result of `getcwd` will be encoded in UTF-8, you might want to look into `OsString` which is specifically meant to contain those.

Comment: @pyon: might as well use `as *mut c_char` in case `c_char` ever changes.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yep, you're right. I just looked at the code snippet, and assumed that `i8` would be the right type under all circumstances, which you rightly point it needn't be.

Comment: @MatthieuM. `OsString` has *no* inherent relationship to C strings.  For example, on Windows, `OsString` is WTF-8, whilst C strings are *guaranteed* to be in some *other* encoding (since Win32 doesn't know what WTF-8 is).

Comment: @DK.: Oh, nice. Why should I assume sanity...

Comment: thanks to your comments, I was now able to compile, but I've run into the next issue: the resulting string is now empty..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **most** cases, you should just use [`env::current_dir`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html). This correctly handles all the platform-specifics for you, such as the "other" encodings mentioned in the comments.

---

C strings are kind of terrible. `getcwd` fills a buffer of some length, but doesn't tell you where it ends; you have to manually find the terminating `NUL` byte.

```
extern crate libc;

static BUF_BYTES: usize = 4096;

fn main() {
    let buf = unsafe {
        let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(BUF_BYTES);
        let res = libc::getcwd(buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut i8, buf.capacity());
        if res.is_null() {
            panic!("Not long enough");
        }
        let mut len = 0;
        while *buf.as_mut_ptr().offset(len as isize) != 0 { len += 1 }
        buf.set_len(len);
        buf
    };

    let s = String::from_utf8(buf).expect("Found invalid UTF-8");
    println!("result: {}", s);
}
```

> seems that buf.len() returns 0

Yes, the length is zero because no one told the vector that data was added. Vectors are comprised of three parts - a pointer to data, a length, and a *capacity*.

The capacity is how much memory is available, the size is how much is used. When treating the vector as a blob to store data into, you want to use the capacity. You then need to inform the vector how many of those bytes were used, so that `String::from_utf8` knows where the end is.

You'll note that I changed the scope of `unsafe` to only include the truly unsafe aspects and the code that makes that code actually safe.

---

In fact, you could just copy [the implementation of `env::current_dir` for Unix-like systems](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.9.0/src/libstd/sys/unix/os.rs#L95-L119). It handles the failure cases much nicer and uses the proper types (paths **aren't** strings). Of course, it's even easier to just call `env::current_dir`. ^_^

---

> fyi: I ended up with this
>
> ```
> extern crate libc;
>
> use std::ffi::CStr;
> use std::io;
> use std::str;
>
> static BUF_BYTES: usize = 4096;
>
> fn main() {
>   let buf = unsafe {
>       let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(BUF_BYTES);
>       let ptr = buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut libc::c_char;
>       if libc::getcwd(ptr, buf.capacity()).is_null() {
>           panic!(io::Error::last_os_error());
>       }
>       CStr::from_ptr(ptr).to_bytes()
>   };
>   println!("result: {}", str::from_utf8(buf).unwrap());
> }
> ```

This is **unsafe** and will lead to crashes (in the best case) or silent memory corruption or worse.

When a block ends, any variables within it will be dropped. In this case, the `unsafe` block creates `buf`, takes a pointer to it, makes a `CStr` with the pointer, then *frees the `Vec`*, invalidating the pointer. It then returns that `CStr` containing an invalid reference from the block.

Something like this is better:

```
extern crate libc;

use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};
use std::io;
use std::str;

static BUF_BYTES: usize = 4096;

fn main() {
    let buf = unsafe {
        // Allocate some space to store the result
        let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(BUF_BYTES);

        // Call the function, panicking if it fails
        let ptr = buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut libc::c_char;
        if libc::getcwd(ptr, buf.capacity()).is_null() {
            panic!(io::Error::last_os_error());
        }

        // Find the first NUL and inform the vector of that
        let s = CStr::from_ptr(ptr);
        buf.set_len(s.to_bytes().len());

        // Transfer ownership of the Vec to a CString, ensuring there are no interior NULs
        CString::new(buf)
    };

    let s = buf.expect("Not a C string").into_string().expect("Not UTF-8");
    println!("result: {}", s);
}
```

---

> I wonder why this has actually worked

Likely because nothing changed the memory before you attempted to access it. In a heavily multithreaded environment, I could see more issues arising.

> why is it possible to have two mutable references to the vector? First as `mut buf` and then as `ptr = buf.as_mut_ptr()`. The ownership has not moved, has it? Otherwise, why is it possible to call `buf.capacity()`

You don't actually have two *references*. `buf` owns the value, then you get a *mutable pointer*. There is no compiler protection for pointers, which is part of the reason that an `unsafe` block is needed

Comment: thanks a lot that you took time to write this extensive answer. I'm new both to rust and to os programming, so this gives me quite some pointers which will be valuable in the future. Yes, I could use `env::current_dir` but I'm trying to be as close to Unix programming as possible.

Comment: @PhilippKeller It *is* "Unix programming" -> See the [implementation of `env::current_dir`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.9.0/src/libstd/env.rs#L48-L50) and its [inner implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.9.0/src/libstd/sys/unix/os.rs#L95-L119). Don't think that because Rust has a nice interface that it's doing something inane.

Comment: I'm reading "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment" which is a guided reference to "unix programming in C" with all the function definitions and memory constructs. That's why I want to stay with null terminated strings and all these "obstacles" for now. Thanks for the hint that the actual implementation in `std::env::current_dir`

Comment: fyi: I ended up with this: https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/6a9d4787c8962d9dd0f975432cd1e0bc -  CStr has a `from_ptr` function which converts the `NUL` terminated string into an array. Also, io has `io::Error::last_os_error` so the external `errno` crate is not needed

Comment: @PhilippKeller see my update discussing why that's a bad idea.

Comment: oh dear, of course! I wonder why this has actually worked. Thanks for the corrected code plus the comments. What I wondered was: why is it possible to have two mutable references to the vector? First as `mut buf` and then as `ptr = buf.as_mut_ptr()`. The ownership has not moved, has it? Otherwise, why is it possible to call `buf.capacity()`?